# Посмотрите на код, как легче написать, можно ли в одну строку написать?

Tags: python

Описать процедуру PowerA234(A, B, C, D), вычисляющую вторую, третью и четвертую степень числа A и возвращающую эти степени соответственно в переменных B, C и D (A — входной, B, C, D — выходные параметры; все параметры являются вещественными). С помощью этой процедуры найти вторую, третью и четвертую степень пяти данных чисел. Буду благодарен за вашу помощь.

```
import random
def PowerA234(A,B):
   B[0] = A * A
   B[1] = B[0] * A
   B[2] = B[1] * A
   return
A = random.randrange(-10,10)
B = [None] * 3
PowerA234(A,B)
print('A = ', A)
print('B = ', B)
A = random.uniform(-10,10)
PowerA234(A,B)
print('A = ', A)
print('B = ', B)`
```

Comment: Это требуется сделать именно на питоне?

Comment: да, если можете, сделайте пожалуйста по-другому более легче

Comment: Питон передает параметры по значению, для числового типа это (вернуть другие параметры процедуры) сделать нельзя без извратов. Точное условие не помешает.

Comment: На Питоне как бы нет прямого способа вернуть значения через переменные, указанные как аргументы функции. Есть куча обходных путей, на зачем? Почему просто не вернуть степени как результат функции (список или кортеж)?

Comment: @Crand, хорошо как по-другому написать тогда с помощью кортежов и списков? Я новичок, просто то получается то нет.

Comment: return b,c,d, но это не соответствует спецификации вопроса (вероятно, кривой, или речь шла не о питоне)

Comment: В одну строчку - это, например, так: `B,C,D = (A ** i for i in range(2,5))`.

Comment: @Alex,  можете написать по своему, он не обязательно  должен похож на мою. Понимаю, условия задачи  не соответствует питону, т.к сборник направлен больше к С/С++, но нас заставляют.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def PowerA234(cifra):
    stepen2, stepen3, stepen4  = cifra ** 2, cifra ** 3, cifra ** 4
    return f'Cifra = {cifra} \
    Wtoraya stepen = {stepen2}, Tertyaya stepen = {stepen3}, 
    Chetwyortaya stepen = {stepen4}'

cifra = random.randrange(-10,10)
print(PowerA234(cifra))

cifra = random.uniform(-10,10)
print(PowerA234(cifra))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Можно переименовать переменные stepen(x) соответственно по условию на A, B, C....

Comment: В задании входные и выходные данные вещественные, то есть числа. А вы строку возвращаете

Comment: Строку написал чтобы было читабелным и понятным... можно убрать оттуда текст, и оставить результаты типа {stepenX}

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот в пайтоне есть 2 типа данных: изменяемые и неизменяемые. Первые передаются по ссылке, а вторые по значению. Поэтому задача не под пайтон, но если вам ооочень нужно сделать именно так как написано, то

```
import random


def PowerA234(A, B, C, D):
   B[0] = A * A
   C[0] = B[0] * A
   D[0] = C[0] * A
   return


A = random.randrange(-10,10)
B, C, D = [0], [0], [0]

PowerA234(A, B, C, D)
print('A = ', A)
print('B = ', B[0])

A = random.uniform(-10,10)
PowerA234(A, B, C, D)
print('A = ', A)
print('B = ', B[0])
```

А вот  это python way. И переменные A, B, C, D требуют нормальных имен.

```
import random


def power_a234(v):
   a = pow(v, 2)
   b = pow(v, 3)
   c = pow(v, 4)
   return a, b, c


A = random.randrange(-10, 10)
B, C, D = power_a234(A)
print('A = ', A)
print('B = ', B)
print('C = ', C)
print('D = ', D)

A = random.uniform(-10, 10)
B, C, D = power_a234(A)
print('A = ', A)
print('B = ', B)
print('C = ', C)
print('D = ', D)
```

А теперь ответ на вопрос как это в одну строку сделать

```
import random


def power_a234(v):
   return map(lambda x: pow(v, x), [2, 3, 4])


A = random.randrange(-10, 10)
B, C, D = power_a234(A)
print('A = ', A)
print('B = ', B)
print('C = ', C)
print('D = ', D)

A = random.uniform(-10, 10)
B, C, D = power_a234(A)
print('A = ', A)
print('B = ', B)
print('C = ', C)
print('D = ', D)
```